# How to reset api cache in chrome?

Tags: api, google-chrome, caching

For some reason I am getting following response in chrome for some of my api requests `Status Code:200 OK (from disk cache)` I need to disable / clear associated disk cache in order to get fresh endpoint response. Tried clearing out chrome's cache but this is still happening.

Request detail minus some private data:
[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot of chrome network tab? include request and response headers

Comment: @tomcater added them in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because response type is svg/xml, browser count it as a static content and cache it by **url** as **cache key**, try to call your api with additional random query string parameter.

like this
 http://myserver/myapi/action?rand=123456789

with this workaround every time browser request data from server not cache.

here is javascript code for generate new random number

```
var rand = (new Date()).getTime();
```